# How to show product default code (internal reference) in Pos Receipt (Odoo13)

Tags: jquery, xml, odoo-13, point-of-sale

I want to show product default code in pos receipt. Can I inherit or edit in models.js or from other ?
Thanks.

```
export_for_printing: function(){
        return {
            ...
            default_code:    this.get_default_code(),
        };
    },


 get_default_code: function(){
        return this.product.default_code;
    },
```

Comment: there is a jquery template on the point of sale on the static/src/XML file where the receipt template is there. you need to extend that and add your custom code it will be on the receipt.

Comment: @Dipen Shah , I extended the template : OrderReceipt and I added  <t t-esc='line.default_code' /> ; to add fields from model product.product or product.template ; I shoud add it in models.js?

Answer (score 3):

Revise the Solution:

To get the product's other field access you need to do customization in the `JS` & `XML` template.

**JS Code:**

```
odoo.define('ypour_app.your app', function (require) {
"use strict";

var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
var OrderlineSuper = models.Orderline;
models.Orderline = models.Orderline.extend({
   export_for_printing : function() {
        var data = OrderlineSuper.prototype.export_for_printing.call(this);
        // this.get_product() => you can have here all the product data [barcode/default_code/ etc.]
        data.product_default_code = this.get_product().default_code;
        return data;
    }
});
```

});

**XML Code:**

```
<t t-extend="OrderReceipt">
    <t t-jquery="t[t-foreach*='receipt.orderlines']" t-operation="append">
        <b>Default Code </b>: <t t-esc="line.product_default_code"/>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: I got error : Cannot read property 'default_code' of undefined

Comment: <t t-jquery=".orderlines" t-operation='replace'>                              <t t-foreach='receipt.orderlines' t-as='line'> ....                                 <t t-if='!simple'>                                                                                  <t t-esc='line.product_id.default_code' />

Comment: Try this : <t t-esc="line.get_product().default_code"/>

Comment: TypeError:dict.line.get_product is not a function

Comment: @Ing I have edit the answer. you can test the code for your reference.